# How do I install software on Fedora 13?

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

I installed Fedora 13, but it doesn't come with a lot of software I want -- office tools, productivity, GUI environments, MySQL, and Kamailio. How do I get all this stuff onto my Fedora install?

Comment: Let me Google that for you with your question subject: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/User_Guide/chap-User_Guide-Managing_software.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `Fedora 13` To find and install a new package, on the GNOME panel click on 
`System → Administration → Add/Remove Software`, or run the `gpk-application` command at the shell prompt. Provide the `root` password and you are set to go and select and install the softwares that are not otherwise installed by default but available through the media that was used for system installation.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Using_Add_Remove_Software.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using Fedora, but I believe it uses `yum` for package management. You can find and download necessary programs that you need from Fedora's repo.

For example you want to install mysql, type `yum install mysql` in terminal as root. You can do a search first to check if the package is available in the repos with `yum search kamailio`.